# LLVM Clang 6.0 fatal error when building a huge C++ source code on OSX

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, clang++

I'm building a pretty huge source code, which builds just fine with MS compiler and Intel compiler, but Clang ends up with this:

> fatal error: error in backend: Section too large, can't encode r_address (0x1000008) into 24 bits of scattered relocation entry.

If I remove half of it, it starts working fine, so obviously there are some limitations. This seems to be a well known issue from XCode 4.5, but now it's XCode 6.2 and it still doesn't work!! Any options I could enable to make it work? For example on Windows I needed to use /BIGOBJ to make the compiler work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by cutting the source file into multiple source files. It's quite a shame that a compiler bug can cause this as it may be a lot of work and can degrade performance unless the compiler provides global optimizations.